# Infinite Animation of ImageView coming from outside the screen

Tags: android

I want to have an infinite Animation of an `ImageView`. The start position of the `ImageView` should be top outside of the screen and the destination should be bottom outside of the screen.

Is there a mechanic to implement infinite animations and can i place `ImageView`'s outside of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margin out the imageView from left or right of relative Layout as the width of your image. so it will be out of screen

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/test" />
```

Then you can make animation using .
**res/anim/rotatemove.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart" />

</set>
```

now in your activity use

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotatemove);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        iv.startAnimation(anim);

    }
```